# 'Events' Attribute missing on the ZiggeoApi object when using v2

Tags: javascript

I've got a problem with v2 of ziggeo.

**Following is my case:**

I'm using ziggeo from that url:

```
//assets-cdn.ziggeo.com/v2-stable/ziggeo.js
```

I initialise it with the following code:

```
new ZiggeoApi.V2.Application({
    token: {TOKEN},
    language: {LANGUAGE},
    webrtc_streaming: true
});
```

And if I output 'ZiggeoApi' the following appears:
[image: screen shot 2018-03-23 at 18 35 40]

So the main problem is now that 'Events' doesnt exist in the object. And if I use the following code which I got from your site (Here: https://ziggeo.com/docs/sdks/javascript/browser-integration/embed-methods#javascript-version=v2) with that at the beginning:

```
ZiggeoApi.Events.on("system_ready", function() {
```

... it doesn't work and produces an error. Because of the missing 'Events' Attribute I'm also not able to use any other functionality which is connected with events.

When I change the version to *v1-stable* in the url it's working.

Is this a bug or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. You have to do it this way:

Initialise the app:

```
let app = new ZiggeoApi.V2.Application({
    token: {TOKEN},
    language: {LANGUAGE},
    webrtc_streaming: true
});
```

Then call the 'on ready' function directly on the initialised object:

```
app.on('ready', function() {
  // do what you want!
});
```

That's the way how you have to do it with Ziggeo V2.